# Not correctly display first avatar

Tags: android, image, imageview

I use ImageLoader, and display image in ListView, when havent image, server give me String "null", i have check:

```
if(!image.equals("null")) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(image, avatar);
}
```

If not verified, then there should be an empty area, so all ListView item. But if first item .equals("null") , then first image same pattern as last item image, if onStop and onResume Activity, then image first item empty.
Why is this happening? If image.equals("null") then area must be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use poistion on getView(), Based on the scrolling

1. Fetch the value
2. Check if value exists then set value
   else null
3. use ViewHolder effectively